# How much of a film's revenue comes from its cinema release?

Tags: film-industry

Very often when a film's success is being judged, its opening few weeks takings are considered.  However many films and franchises also generate revenue from DVD/BluRay sales and merchandise.

What proportion of a typical modern action film's income comes from its box office takings?

Comment: It depends on the film and the nature of the release. 40% to home video and 28% to theatrical is a studio film from the 90's those numbers are very, very outdated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Creative Skill Set](http://www.creativeskillset.org/film/knowledge/article_5103_1.asp) website breaks it down in general for you:

> Theatrical (ie. cinema) revenues only account for about 25% of the total revenues, with video (including DVD) taking about 40%; television accounting for 28% and ancillary revenues the final 7%.

The website goes on to say:

> How Revenue Flows Through the Marketplace
>
> The main revenue streams for filmed entertainment are:
>
> - Theatrical exhibition
> - Video/DVD rental
> - Video/DVD retail (or sell-through)
> - Pay per View Television
> - Subscription or Pay Television
> - Free Television
>
> The industry has created windows of exploitation to maximise revenues
>   at each stage of the value chain and avoid any clashes in the
>   marketplace. These windows are starting to close up as the
>   non-theatrical streams start to eclipse the original release in terms
>   of revenue generation (although the cinematic shop window still
>   remains the main driver of revenues throughout the chain in most
>   cases) but are roughly as indicated below:
>
> - Theatric: 0 - 6 Months
> - Video/DVD: 6 - 15 Months
> - Pay Per View: 15 - 18
> - Months Pay TV: 18 - 30 Months
> - Free TV: 30 + Months

The website has a lot more information on how and who makes money from a film.